# I'm a billionaire, how would I set up a incorruptible communist society?

Tags: society, economy, communism

I'm a billionaire with unlimited funds/political influence. It is my belief that communism has always failed because in the real world *true* communism has never been tested, rather every time it's been tried it's been corrupted in some way.

As a bored billionaire I'd like to run an experiment with *pure and fair* communism. Following this we will know for sure if communism is successful or not. But I am unsure how to set up the experiment.

Here’s my initial idea of how I’d set up the scenario:

> I’d pick 5000 able bodied volunteers with a vast array of
> intelligence, ideologies and skills with a slight bias towards trades
> like farming, carpentry, fishing, building etc. They all speak the
> same language. They’re placed is a large warm area roughly 100,000 ha
> and provided with basic tools, seeds, domestic animals, some building
> materials & 6 months’ worth of food. This area has no infrastructure
> on it. It is 30% forested with the rest being relatively farmable, there is also
> a large river for fishing. On the outside of town there is a free
> hospital that’s fully staffed that they can access only if they need
> medication or surgery. Once the experiment is started no one can
> leave.

> To maintain communism there is an outside police force within
> the experiment to make sure that all food, land, possessions are
> fairly distributed amongst the whole population. (The police people
> aren’t part of the experimental population and after their shift is
> over, they get to return home and live a typical western life).

Win conditions:

> If the population can sustain 5 years of growth and an overall
> increase in happiness and wellbeing (not sure how I’d measure that). I
> would be content that communism is a successful ideology.  If the
> population starts majorly declining, major malnourishment or high
> counts of violence the experiment will be a failure.

I am open to suggestions on how this scenario can be improved.

How involved should the police be? Should wealth redistribution happen every day, month, year?

Are the win conditions fair? Is the population growth the best measure for a flourishing community?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139113/discussion-on-question-by-jerome-im-a-billionaire-how-would-i-set-up-a-incorru).

Comment: Having external police is a Very Bad Idea. It makes the situation an Us vs. Them with the police having too much power. A better idea is to have the police be part of the population, and the job rotates to everyone for some time of the year. Likewise, have the judges be people from the community.

Comment: Before you attempt to set up such a scheme, it would be nice if you could cite any culture or society that actually operated the way you envision, and that you would be pleased to go live under. Just one in the history of the planet.

Comment: 5 years is much too short. It does not even begin to address such obvious issues as what happens to children. You need something like one generation, 25 years at least.

Comment: Also, 5000 people living at a billionaire's expense is not a society, it's a zoo.

Comment: "communism has always failed because in the real world true communism has never been tested" but then you go on to artificially construct your society to fit your needs. If you wish to prove communism would work were it not for corruption, then you should be picking people either at random or representative of society as a whole. Also it's 5000 people funded by a billionaire - the cost of the society for the 5000 people must be cheap enough that it's affordable when expanded to the whole world (or country).

Comment: This is a highly opinion based question. Also: You can't have communism without the force of the State to back it up, so by definition, your communist hippy commune funded by a billionaire is by definition "not real Communism" either. 

As a complete aside and total opinion, I think Communism should be reviled at least as much as Nazism. Both are authoritarian systems that put the State as sacrosanct, and Communism has the higher body count.

Comment: I suspect this fairly legitimate question which was basically "How can a rich billionaire run a social experiment" was closed mostly because people don't like communism, or rich billionaires running social experiments, given the comments. Posts shouldn't be closed because you don't like the politics of governments. There are many reprehensible governments in worldbuilding that have fine answers.

Comment: Please define "fairly distributed" How is food, land, possessions, means of production, intellectual property,etc valued?  Who/what determines value, ie the police, independent third party, market forces in the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need several additions to make it fair.

## A control

An outsider could easily say they were fine because you provided them with whatever they needed. As such, you need another 5000 in a similar area without the police force.

## External challenges.

Real civilizations face challenges, like shortages of resources, or surpluses. How do they handle if one particular location has an excessive resource? Do a few tests, like dumping in some useful resource, or removing access to a valuable resource to see how they handle adversity and surplus, or requiring them to produce a certain amount of goods or trained people in a set time.

## You need to teach communism.

Both places should obviously have access to people to teach them communism, along with supporting their education and improvement with books. You want them following your ideology, so obviously you want to give them a chance to learn if they lack knowledge. Maybe the capitalist haven will choose communism as well.

## You need to keep them from dying.

They might fuck up badly, and you need to keep them from death. If anyone is close to starvation or dehydration, you can remove them from the experiment. This will obviously be a mark against whatever rewards they get for success.

## Measure objective measures.

Nutrition, education, mental health, and fitness. If you just measure happiness, people will assume you just pressured people to say that they're happy. See what actually happened to them.

## The police should be under the control of the people.

Get a few competent communists you trust to run them. They can make them run more or less often as needed. Maybe they'll be needed more in the early days or less later on.

## Prepare an early start.

A bad rainstorm early on could end your experiment when people start dying of exposure. You'll need some early amenities like tents and such so that they can survive the elements, along with some food and basic supplies. You could provide them with a month of food and water, enough clothes to manage a year of weather, and give them access to tents for a month so they have time to set up.

Everyone should be given a radio and access to batteries so that they can radio for help in an emergency. You could have a team on hand to rescue people, with points deducted if they call on you.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response. Just some follow up questions if you don't mind. Would generating food/shelter be enough of an external challenge to test the subjects or would I need something more? Is the externally staffed hospital sufficient for keeping them from needlessly dying? How would I prevent the police force from becoming corrupt if they are regulated by one or a few people? How would I know the leaders of the police are competent?

Comment: I like the point about objective measures. Much better than generic happiness.

Comment: It should be luxury food and shelter ideally, so that the people have a chance to see if they can on their own distribute rarer goods out fairly. For example, providing them with a crate of chocolate, or coffee. And not enough to survive on, since they are supposed to gather food from the environment. 

I added some stuff on an early start supply. You should make sure these settlers have some supplies, so they have time to build up some infrastructure and skills. They are there for five years, so you have time.

You should have access to radios and nature types to rescue people.

Answer (score 8):

This is a frame challenge, too long to fit in a comment.

The reason communism has failed is not really that it has always become corrupt. It always becomes corrupt because it cannot work; it is inherently at odds with human nature.

Specifically, the philosophy is "from each according to their ability, to each according to their needs."

But that means it makes no difference what your abilities are, you get the same food, shelter, medical care, no matter what. And you get that no matter what your abilities, and no matter if you exercise them or don't. It doesn't matter how hard you work; you can't "get ahead". If you bust your ass to become a doctor, you don't make a dime more than if you coast through school and become a warehouse worker. In fact you'll have considerably more fun and free time coasting through school. More romance. More sex. More time to play pointless card and board games.

It is human nature to work for rewards, and praise, and respect, and to live better than average. But communism, if strictly enforced, demands **everyone** live the average life. Dummies, Geniuses, and all in-between, *regardless* of their ability.

Thus "from each according to their ability" means we get less and less every decade; because those with inherent, born potential for ability are no longer motivated to do better. Their fate is sealed, grades don't matter, effort doesn't matter, everyone ends up with the same (declining) standard of living.

As in Communist Russia, the only route to improve your lot is crime. And then they implement a police state, and a slave labor state, and that just increases the incentives toward violent crime.

The amount of money used up by corruption in Russia was minuscule compared to the potential of their economy. The corruption occurred because the rules of communism created highly efficient organized crime enterprises that infiltrated the government to pilfer wealth directly from the state owned industrial apparatus; oil and gas primarily.

What does work, time and again, with a similar goal to Communism, is called Social democracy. This is more like our naturally evolved system of tribal government; and consistent with typical human motives and altruism.

In this system, instead of trying to impose a single standard of living on everybody, the government imposes a relatively high **floor** on *poverty*, using high taxes. This has been particularly effective and proven, particularly in Nordic countries.

Meaning, nobody goes hungry. Medical care and medicine is free (at the point of consumption). Nobody goes without adequate, though minimal, shelter. Education is free (at the point of consumption). Taxes run about 40% of income. The State owns all natural resources in the country; operates and sells them, but accounting is open, and the proceeds are invested and a fixed inflation proof percentage of the income is used to support the government, and thereby lower the income taxes on the populace. Nobody suffers, dies, or lives a shorter life for lack of wealth.

The key is that citizens can seek more than the minimal life, and even though nobody is *required* to work, well over 95% of them *do* work. And those born with special skills can rise above; there are mega-millionaires in these countries, with huge estates and houses, private jets and airplanes. People can get rich in business, in entertainment, in the stock market, by gambling and so forth. There are various safeguards to prevent government officials from self-dealing I will not detail; but ultimately citizens have far more control over government expenses than we do in the USA or most countries.

Communism does not work. I think we can make a similar argument for why pure Capitalism does not work. In pure Capitalism, the wealth of individuals grows exponentially, at the expense of the masses, until there is a revolt, a crash, a deep economic depression. People get sick or starve and die simply for lack of money. There would be no public services like police our courts, if you want protection, buy guns, hire your own guards. You only get healthcare or medicine if you can afford it, and if it is lifesaving, they've got you over a barrel.

What does work, and has been proven time and again, is a balanced mixture of the two; Social Democracy. Instead of a *ceiling* on wealth, we put a *floor* on poverty.

Your experiment would probably work on a small scale; meaning 150 or fewer adults. In numerous scientific studies, we find this is the average capacity of a human to remember people in their "tribe". It is shown on social media and many other population studies. Between 150 and 200 adults, groups start to fission, and break into "us vs them" groups. That is when Communism breaks down, too, when a small group starts considering another group rivals, and eventually enemies that can be victimized or punished for "taking" or "stealing" the resources that rightfully belong to *our* group.

Because we have children and grow, tribes naturally fission, a group of males and females splinter off and go their own way to make their own fortune.

That is a working model as long as growth is relatively slow and resources are relatively abundant; but eventually we reach the carrying capacity of the available resources, and the result is war. If the environment can no longer support all of us, the population must be reduced, and it will be "them", not "us". (The same thing happens with deprivations caused by either Capitalism or Communism; we fracture into "us" and "them" groups.)

No political system can overcome that; but in the modern world, Zero Population Growth is possible with simple birth control, and a more tribe-friendly political system like Social Democracy can last forever by minimizing or eliminating the life-threatening deprivations that drive these schisms.

I don't think your experiment will work, or prove anything. I don't believe it is possible for Communism to succeed on anything but the micro-scale, of 150 adults or less living and working together every day to survive.

**EDIT:** This edit was added in response to a question in comments by the OP.

*Q: Would an experiment with 150 people possibly be successful but anything larger than that, regardless of the parameters, ultimately fail?*

Yes. WL Gore is a multi-billion dollar company, founded by a chemical engineer in 1958, and governed by his rules, still. He studied this problem too, and discovered that in a plant, around 180 to 220 employees, he could no longer sustain a "we" culture, that the culture became "us" vs "them", employees vs "management". He mandated that no plant shall exceed 160 employees; if it did, the plant split, another plant was built, governed *independently*, volunteers seeded it and hired new employees to meet the demand.

WL Gore is run as a democracy, rather inverted. Groups of up to 20 workers elect a manager from their group; and can recall that manager at any time. Those managers do the same for their next level manager: They elect their manager, and can take a vote and recall their manager at any time, to the lower level, sending somebody else from their group to take his place. Plant managers are elected the same way; as are regional managers, all the way up to the CEO. Last I read that was a woman, but she can be recalled to be a vice president at any time by the other vice presidents.

There are some caveats in legal terms, but that is basically the structure throughout. New recruits are not hired for a specific job, accepted applicants have to try out working for different groups, and be accepted by one of them to be hired permanently. They have the choice to leave their group, but it is up to them to find another group if they want to continue working. They can also try out at another plant.

It may not sound like it works, but it has worked for decades. WL Gore has a very distinct culture that encourages independence, research and invention at every level by any employee.

You *might* be able to structure your society similarly, in villages that cooperate, but even WL Gore fires people for all the normal transgressions; from not pulling their weight to actual crimes. And WL Gore is governed externally by the laws, local and federal police forces of the USA (and other countries if they operate there; I don't know).

In an actual society, you have to figure out how you will govern, and with the stated goals of communism, I don't see how you address shirkers, cheats, frauds, and violent criminals. Does your experiment allow putting murderers to death?

Or is that the jackboot "law enforcement" you envision? If you need a separate **force** element outside the society, you prove nothing about whether communism "works" on any scale, your citizens are basically slaves if they cannot govern themselves and have zero control over the laws you dictated. You have a monarchy and rule by force; not "Communism". And that is what Russia discovered, as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139152/discussion-on-answer-by-amadeus-im-a-billionaire-how-would-i-set-up-a-incorrup).

Answer (score 2):

There are some assumptions behind Communism that doom it. One assumption is about knowing the world enough to be able to manage things. Another assumption is on human nature and the wanting to be equal.

The biggest reason that Communism fails is a lack of knowledge. The communist system is built on assuming that the central authority can know fully. This is a false assumption. A centralized economic planning system fails because it cannot know all the local factors that affect the local economy. Workers cannot properly manage a factory because they don't know all the needs of their customers. And on and on.

It is not possible to know all the local issues and how to solve them and know what the future changes will be. Most importantly, it is not possible to know where we need to be investing in order to meet tomorrow's needs.

The Marxist vision of workers running the factories and farm hands running the farms is based on an assumption of slowly changing conditions - changing so slowly that workers and farm hands *could* know the conditions and needs. However, this assumption massively fails in today's world.

What happens is that in a changing environment, some people will learn about situations before others do and will be able to profit from that knowledge. The most extreme cases today include setting up computers where the information about stock trade requests hit those computers before it hits other computers and being able to change prices and / or initiate other trades based on that knowledge.

The more centralized the planning, the slower it responds to conditions in the world. (For example, there was a study on emergency response teams for cities / states / countries. The more centralized the control, the more people died in the emergencies.)

Economic equality is a noble goal, but it has as an assumption that people want others to be equal with them. That works in some families and fails in others. It works in some tribal groups. But it fails miserably in societies where people do not feel like the rest of society is "like them". It fails when some people feel as if they are not part of society.

Comment: @Amadeus Ok, but how would _you_ describe the way that females compete for top status and how would you report when women have boasted about getting other women to follow their cycle? The process of wanting to be top in human society occurs in both men and women and that process is destructive to the Communist ideal.

Comment: You don't know how that works; it has been studied. If cycles move, they gradually move toward the average. For women already near the average, there is little change. But that doesn't mean they are "dominant", it is pure chance they were near the average. The majority of humans compete for status, it is not gender specific, it is survival specific, for all animals that evolved in tribes. Higher status males **and** females are more likely to pass on their genes and for their offspring to survive. Sorry. You are just wrong.

Comment: If more centralised planning is always slower, then why do enormous vertically integrated corporations, which centrally plan their own logistics/production/distribution, seem to respond to the digital age much faster than small scale, un centrally planned shops etc?

Comment: @BugCatcherNakata "seem to" are the operative words. They have a common internal communications process. But they are often following examples from smaller companies that are not well known. The large corporations are buying / copying inventions from smaller companies or buying the smaller companies. For example, Apple has purchased quite a number of smaller companies in order to get the inventions. The large companies can scale these inventions far better than smaller companies can.

Comment: To give Amadeus's comments more rigor, here is the NIH article on the subject showing that female cycle synchronization is simple folk lore. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26181612/

Comment: I can't speak about innovations, but in terms of logistics/planning/resource allocation/warehousing/etc companies like amazon and walmart are much much more efficient because of their whole-of-supply chain centralised planning than small shops and distributors relying on price signals and individual contracts alone

Answer (score 2):

### Try faith

Frame challenge:
Communal living with no property defies several basic human needs, and thus economics.

People do like to be rewarded for work, and some are more industrious than others, and expect a greater reward. Some inequality is *good*; it's good that someone who wants to work hard and provide for others is rewarded more than someone who does the bare minimum. It's *good* that someone lazy can live an undemanding lifestyle without being parasitic.

Marxism denies this, and tries to paper over human desires by force or ideology that only a few believe in.

There's only one force that has ever resulted in groups of people that all genuinely care more about the successes of their commune than their own individual desires (either to be lazy or be rich). That is religion. Whether it be God's calling / selection bias, or transformative power / indoctrination, religious communes actually have persisted for long periods of time.

The Dead Sea Essenes, early Christians, the monasteries of Europe, arguably the kibbutzim* arguably the Amish, lots of little Christian or obscure cult communes.

It still doesn't last forever, but it can persist for a while. AFAIK there are no Marxist communes older than a few years.

- In this case, having a deadly outside enemy may well have been the main factor; nationalism or ideology can emulate religion,but not for long.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are trying to describe is an extreme form of worker cooperative, not actual communism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worker_cooperative Traditional economic theory assumes that people are rational and therefore chase profit. But of course there is a limit to what you can do with wealth. Why would someone agree to forego profit? Why would someone step into a dangerous rocket and agree to live with other people in a space station? There is little profit in that. Not to mention that you would have to leave everything behind. So maybe there are people who are plain irrational. Are they also criminal? I will have to go on a limb here because I don't have hard data, but as far as I know the political system does not determine the amount of crime. Except for extreme cases when being part of a certain group is sort of crime already.
Monthly distribution is I think easiest to do. A week is too short, a year too long. Population growth could be your goal. But I think it would be easier to just use questionnaires to assess happiness. Besides if you start to reward people for having many children, you might end up with neglected children.

Answer (score 1):

### No. Requiring external police negates the results

One of the worst aspects of every communist society is the security forces. Removing them from the test negates all predictions from the test for a society where the police are not external. Define 'fair', btw.

### No, the absolute power that Marxism hands the state corrupts absolutely

Inevitably, because Marxist economics doesn't work, dissidents demand a change; the people who run the police also control all aspects of the economy, and they *will* use the economy to further their political aims. It happens in non communist countries but because the government is not all powerful, it's not as bad.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot set up an incorruptible society, because any society will be run by people, and people are corruptible.**

Comment: The question is asking for an experiment in communism. Not an experiment in 'incorruptibility'

Comment: @BugCatcherNakata "I'm a billionaire, how would I set up an incorruptible communist society?"  That is the question, isn't it?

Comment: Fair enough, I guess it turns on the question of whether 'incorruptible communist society' means that the communism is incorruptible or the people are. Given the proposal for police to redistribute resources each month I interpreted it to mean that the system itself is robust and won't get corrupted into a non-communist society, but I can see your interpretation too

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but what you are describing is not communism. It sounds like some sort of tribal communalism with an external force arbitrarily distributing resources, and such an experiment would surely be guaranteed to fail. I think the important distinction is that communism doesn't mean that everyone has exactly the same amount of stuff, as you and the other answers seem to be assuming. Of course there is no universal definition, but I think you need to bear in mind that a communist systems means that individuals cannot own the means of production (factories, tools, etc.) and therefore profit from work that somebody else does.

Communist ideology is based on a reaction to a situation where one class of people owns the factories, and the other people work for them and make them rich. Eventually, the workers will seize the factories, dispose of the factory owners, and run the factory themselves, sharing in its profits. The key difference here, in my opinion, is this:

> You are describing a system where the products of people's labour are redistributed according to a fixed system. But communism deals with *how those products are produced in the first place*.

If you want to run an experiment on communism, you should come up with a system where the group somehow determines what is or isn't legitimate 'work', and then each hour of legitimate 'work' is rewarded with a fixed amount of resources, no matter how 'valuable' that work was to the society. So my hour of fishing gets me one hour's worth of resources, no matter how many fish I caught, and if I come up with a new fishing method, I can't earn any extra resources from it (apart from the time I spent thinking of it). There might be other ways to organise labour - you don't want *everyone* to become a fisher. You can read more [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communism) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_mode_of_production).

Finally, my suggestion as to how to run an experiment on whether communism works with unlimited political influence, I would say the best use of your time, would be to:

- Remove any sanctions/trade restrictions placed on Cuba and North Korea by the rest of the world
- Give both countries enough nukes that the US or anybody else couldn't invade and make the US promise never to seek regime change in those countries by military or other means
- Otherwise ensure that those countries don't need to waste money on more military spending than their population suggests
- etc
- See what happens.

In my experience, defenders of communism often point to the fact that communist countries become international pariahs, cannot participate in the world economy, are under intense military/psyop pressure from the US, etc etc. So the best experiment would be to just take one of those countries, and let it go. Will it thrive? Or will it suffer low living standards and repression? Let's see...

Answer (score 1):

**There is a number of problems with this experiment**

> I’d pick 5000 able bodied volunteers with a vast array of intelligence, ideologies and skills with a slight bias towards trades like farming, carpentry, fishing, building etc

5000 is much too small a number for any kind of social experiment. Also, I'm not sure about "vast array of ideologies". These people would have to volunteer to take part (unless your billionaire abducts people for his experiment), so they would have to be at least somewhat enthusiastic about communism in the first place.

If your experiment is supposed to test whether an incorruptible society can be created, your setup is not good for that. Five thousand people is too small a number to need an extensive bureaucracy to govern them and it is that bureaucracy which would be likely to be corrupted.

> They’re placed is a large warm area roughly 100,000 ha and provided with basic tools, seeds, domestic animals, some building materials & 6 months’ worth of food.

This already limits the experiment in a number of ways. You're testing whether a very small number of people in a very rural setting in a nice climate where they are given all the tools they need will be happy. This won't tell you whether people living in a more urban setting would be happy, or if people would be able to produce the tools they need or if they would thrive in a harsher climate etc etc. On the other hand, if the experiment were to 'fail' you could say it was because these people only had the barest of necessities and if they had access to nicer things it could've gone better.

What you're testing is pretty much if a small number of people can feed themselves if all resources are shared between the people. This kind of sharing existed in early tribal societies, so it should work. This experiment does not tell you if this form of resource distribution will work with a more complex society.

> To maintain communism there is an outside police force within the experiment to make sure that all food, land, possessions are fairly distributed amongst the whole population. (The police people aren’t part of the experimental population and after their shift is over, they get to return home and live a typical western life).

As others have pointed out, outside police force is another problem. In a communism, police would have to come from within the population.

> If the population can sustain 5 years of growth and an overall increase in happiness and wellbeing (not sure how I’d measure that). I would be content that communism is a successful ideology. If the population starts majorly declining, major malnourishment or high counts of violence the experiment will be a failure.

There are a number of problems there. Five years is way too short. Even the infamous Jonestown project lasted longer than that. People will behave differently if they know that in five years time they will go back to their normal lives - for example they may be more reluctant to start a family.

Measuring wellbeing is difficult. If one person is ecstatically happy and another is miserable, is the overall wellbeing better or worse than if both people were feeling sort of meh?

That's the problem with sociological theories - you can't test them objectively. Any experiment may involve millions of people and last for decades and whatever the outcome you can always say that had history gone the other way things could have turned out differently.